# How do I plot the range of a function that maps $\Bbb R^4$ into $\Bbb R^3$?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I have a rational function (quasilinear),say, $f(x,y,z,t)=(x/z,y/t,x/t)$. 
In my case, the domain is the unit cube in $\Bbb R^4$ and the codomain is the unit simplex in $\Bbb R^3$.

I want to plot the range of the function to see if it is convex or not.

`Plot3D` or `Parameterplot3D` do not let me use more than two variables. Is there a way I can make a plot that will let me visualize the range?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You say that the codomain is the unit simplex, but the range is clearly unbounded if z and t can approach zero.  Or is that statement about a function other than the f(x,y,z,t) you give?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, one can do it symbolically on a tractable problem such as the example:

```
cad = Reduce[
 {p, q, r} == {x/z, y/t, x/t} &&
  0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1 && 0 <= z <= 1 && 0 <= t <= 1 &&
  {p, q, r} ∈ Reals,
 {p, q, r}, {x, y, z, t}]
(*  (p == 0 && q >= 0 && r == 0) || (p > 0 && q >= 0 && r > 0)  *)

RegionPlot3D@ImplicitRegion[cad, {p, q, r}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

A brute force method. It won't work on the OP's example, without adding code to check for nonnumeric results, reasonable plot range clipping, and other sophisticated handling found in the built-in plotters.

Here's a polynomial function:

```
f = Function[{x, y, z, t}, {
    -t^2 x + t x^2 + t^2 y - x^2 y - t y^2 + x y^2,
    -t^2 x + t x^2 + t^2 z - x^2 z - t z^2 + x z^2,
    -t^2 y + t y^2 + t^2 z - y^2 z - t z^2 + y z^2}];
```

We can compile it and plot the image of the unit hypercube, with a tensor product grid.  One can plot the points (commented out below) or the image of the wireframe of the hypercubic mesh.

```
cf = Compile[{{v, _Real, 1}}, f[v[[1]], v[[2]], v[[3]], v[[4]]],
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True},
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True];
With[{n = 8},
 Graphics3D[
   GraphicsComplex[
    cf@Tuples[Range[0., 1., 1./n], 4],
    {(*Point@Range[(n+1)^4],*)
     Thin, ColorData[97, 2],
     Line[
      1 + DeleteCases[{_, {___, i_ /; i > n, ___}}]@
           Flatten[Outer[
             (v \[Function] {{##}, {##} + v}) /@ IdentityMatrix@Length[{##}] &,
             Range[0, n], Range[0, n], Range[0, n], Range[0, n]],
            4] . (n + 1)^Range[0, 3]
      ]}
    ],
   Axes -> True]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]